# Software Bloat - Adding Libraries in Java and Performance

Tags: java, python

I have heard a few arguments from people that It is better to avoid adding a lot of dependencies(Additional libraries like guava etc) to a `java` project.

Their argument is based on the fact that adding too many libraries in `python` slows it down .

I argued against re-implementing functionality already built into a library, I also argued that the compiled nature of java and the compression functionality available in tools such as `proguard` practically void the `python` argument of bloat .

Am I right ? or should I try to minimize the amount of dependencies added to the `java` build ?

Comment: @Charles: Ok So no `software-bloat` tag, How do I represent that in the tagging system then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the main argument against libraries isn't the performance of imported classes, it's more to do with the maintainability of your codebase — if you happily allow your team to mix & match **Guava** & **Apache Commons** for instance, you'll most likely end up with different imports from the two libraries to achieve the same aim in different classes (e.g. Guava Strings vs Apache StringUtils).

Later, if you decide that some similar code across two classes can be refactored into its own class, you've to deal with any discrepancies in the way the two libraries handle things differently.

I would say you are right, but I'd also say of course you should try to minimise the dependencies in the build — you should introduce libraries if necessary to avoid duplication, but only after due consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Class loading in Java should be restricted to the classes you actually end up using. The JIT compiler will also reduce the impact of any bloat. So in most cases you should not experience performance loss due to a large number of dependencies.

Chances are that you will have overlaps between the dependencies in the sense that the same functionality is implemented in different ways. That means you will have a larger installation size (the total of the JARs is larger than what it would have to be) and possibly even more memory consumption due to multiple different classes being loaded that effectively do the same.

Unless you are working with very tight constraints such as deploying to small embedded devices, I would not expect any of this to come even close in harm than the gains you have by not re-inventing the wheel. Not only do you save on development effort, but you will also get more stable code to begin with.

The other big thing in the Java world is Maven, which makes managing dependencies and creating modular software a lot easier than what it used to be. It really shines in a modular setup (don't try it on big, monolithic builds).